# Can "don't mention it" be used after "No. Thank you"?

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions

I had a discussion with my friend. When I offered to help somebody he replied " No. Thank you" and I replied "Don't mention it" and I think it was true to say that. But my friend believes that isn't true cause I didn't do anything for him. I searched about that but I couldn't find anything about this. I found some facts about "don't mention it" but they were not helpful.

Comment: One says "Don't mention it" when you actually do something to help a person and they offer their gratitude. You don't use it when you actually did nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is an actual English language question or merely a question of social convention, but usually we say "don't mention it" when someone thanks us for something we actually did. The literal meaning is that the effort expended wasn't worth thanking someone for, although of course we do often say "don't mention it" even if the effort involved was substantial.

Saying "don't mention it" when someone thanks us for offering to do something but not actually doing it (because the other person declined), is not common.

There isn't any conventional response required for "No, thank you". Depending on circumstances, "maybe next time" might be appropriate.